# docker | unknown environment `bash` | sub process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, containers, dpkg

My goal is to get a docker container running with nordvpn installed and connected.

**Get docker container going**

```
sudo docker pull ubuntu:latest
sudo docker run -it ubuntu bash
// now im in the docker container
apt install update
apt install wget
wget {{nordvpn_link.deb}}
dpkg -i {{nordvpn_link.deb}}
// some errors about dependencies after above command so ...
apt install -f
// then
apt install nordvpn
```

**First big error**

```
root@f706a3f4012f:/home# apt install nordvpn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nordvpn is already the newest version (3.6.0-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up nordvpn (3.6.0-2) ...
[ERROR] Unknown environment `bash'
dpkg: error processing package nordvpn (--configure):
installed nordvpn package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
nordvpn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**I read [here](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/) to run the following command**

```
dpkg --configure -a
// errors
Setting up nordvpn (3.6.0-2) ...
[ERROR] Unknown environment `bash'
dpkg: error processing package nordvpn (--configure):
installed nordvpn package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
nordvpn
```

I am not sure as to why this is happening with the docker container as the process went smoothly on my regular ubuntu desktop installation.

Comment: Something about the postinstall script is failing.  Take a look at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/nordvpn.postinst`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured it out yet or not, but the postinstall script is specifically to configure the systemd/sysvinit scripts.  Since you're running inside a docker container, you don't have either of these.

For those curious, the script looks at the process with PID 1 to decide whether you are running systemd or sysvinit.  However, since this is inside docker, PID 1 is going to belong to whatever command you passed to docker (bash in this case).

You should be able to safely ignore the error as the application has already been installed.